# Bug when displaying images in iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, image

I am a beginner and having problems with iOS when it comes to displaying images. Basically, instead of displaying any images, it just displays a blue blur. I have tried with all sorts of images and also with images that have worked fine in other projects in the past. As I am fairly new, I don't know if this could be a bug or something that I would have changed in the preferences or some other sort of settings problem. To make sure nothing else was going on, I have started a new project and all that project has is a view controller:

h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

- (IBAction)Pressed:(id)sender;

@end
```

m file:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)Pressed:(id)sender {

    UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Image.png"];
    [sender setImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
@end
```

As I've said, I have tried png, jpg, images that work on other projects, etc. This is just a couple of examples of what happens in the simulator when you click the button:

[apple](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jY8wr.png)

[banana](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GPcSf.png)

Just the contour of whatever the image is but in blue. It's very frustrating to say the least. I have tried suggestions I got on here like setting tint color and background to clear to no avail.

```
[sender setTintColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[sender setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```

Also, to begin I thought this might be related to the project I was working on, but's it's happening on any new project I start. Could this be a bug? Is it worth re-installing Xcode from scratch? Does Xcode get this sort of bugs? Any input appreciated.

Comment: try on device and see if the issue still remains!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I know what's going on here. Go to the Images.xcassets and tap on the image that you are having problems (i.e. Image.png). You'll see in the right side, an option that is called Render as, as shown in the following image:

[image]

If this option is set to "Template Image", the system ignores the image’s color information and creates an image stencil based on the alpha values in the image, so I think you have that option set, so you better change it to "Default" (as I have in that example), or "Original Image", so you see it correctly.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Nice, you beat my answer by seconds, with similar images. Deleting mine.

Comment: On a serious note, this does work but only with the option "Original Image". "Default" still displays the blue image. thanks

Comment: Haha not necessary dude! But I'm glad it helped! :D. Thanks for the comment, thought it will work with Default too. Perhaps my Default is Original, and your default is Template.

Comment: @Paul Please mark this question as a correct answer as it did fix your issue :)

Comment: Yes off course, I am trying to figure out how to do it - I am that new

Comment: there, that took some time